# Is my well booster pump GPM is too high, causing pipe erosion?

Tags: water, water-pressure, well-pump, fire-sprinkler

I am suspecting my well booster pump is causing errosion corrosion inside my house where 3/4" copper exists. It is 2 HP and operates at 25-44 GPM. The 1" line outside the house tees off into the fire sprinkler system which is supposed to require 20 GPM.

Is errosion corrosion likely here? Getting a smaller booster pump is complicated by the fire sprinkler requirements. Is there a 10 GPM flow rate limiter I can put at the house (after tee to fire sprinkler system) that would help?

Comment: Also, there is a clunking sound where the water enters the house when the pump turns off and I am getting copper content of 0.5 to 1.0 ppm inside the house (which could be many things, this theory being one of them).

Comment: More detail would be helpful - explain and draw the whole system, rather than just going off on what you suspect. My first guess with corroding copper pipes is either low pH (acid water) or copper and iron pipes conjoined without proper dielectric unions. I sincerely doubt you are getting anything like 25 GPM through your copper pipes, regardless of pump size - but if you can fill your bathtub in two minutes or less, please document that (most are about 50 gallons) and add to the information about your system. Could also be iron pump and copper pipes conjoined...

Comment: @Ecnerwal definitely not getting 25 GPM in the bathtub through 1/2" copper :)... The booster tank fills up at about 50 GPM though (1.25" line) and that is reduced to 1" copper, then reduced again to 3/4" copper. I am more concerned about the effects of the high flow rate at is hits these massive restrictions.

Comment: I agree with Ecnerwal 3. It is more likely that mixed metal plumbing and or high iron content would be to blame. I have also seen where ferrous metal was in contact with copper creating galvanic corrosion that caused leaks.